# create instance variable in erb template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Say I have 2 erb views: a list view and a show view, I want to render the show view inside the list view

list view

```
<% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
  <h2><%= vehicle.type %></h2>
  <ul>
    <% vehicle.accessories.each do |accessory| %>
      <li><% accessory.title %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

show view

```
<h2><%= @vehicle.type %></h2>
<ul>
  <% @vehicle.accessories.each do |accessory| %>
    <li><% accessory.title %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

the issue is the show view takes an `@vehicle` instance variable, how can I pass that down from the parent if I was going to nest these and it still shows up as an instance variable, accessed with `@vehicle`? something like:

```
<% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
  <%= render "show" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you might want to make that `show` view a `partial`. Something like:

```
<h2><%= vehicle.type %></h2>
<ul>
  <% vehicle.accessories.each do |accessory| %>
    <li><% accessory.title %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Then you can do something like:

```
<% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
  <%= render "path/to/show_partial", locals: {vehicle: vehicle} %>
<% end %>
```

Naturally, you'll want to:

- use the real `path/to/show_partial`, whever that happens to be, and
- do some eager loading so that you're not doing a whole bunch of N+1 queries.

Comment: well, the show view can be viewed by itself at times too, would it still work as a partial? also, is the `path/to/show_partial` the path in the routes or is it the path to the file itself?

Comment: Sure, you could render the `_show.html.erb` partial in the `show.html.erb` view. (Note the partial begins with an underscore.) And, the path is the path to the file itself. So, if the `_show.html.erb` partial was saved in `app/views/vehicles`, then you would do something like `render partial: "vehicles/show", locals: {vehicle: vehicle}`.